# How to find the .NET framework version of a Visual Studio project?

Tags: .net, version

I have a project in Visual Studio. How can I find out which .NET Framework version it's for?

Answer (score 122):

It depends which version of Visual Studio:

- In **2002**, all projects use .Net 1.0
- In **2003**, all projects use .Net 1.1
- In **2005**, all projects use .Net 2.0
- In **2008**, projects use .Net 2.0, 3.0, or 3.5; you can change the version in Project Properties
- In **2010**, projects use .Net 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, or 4.0; you can change the version in Project Properties
- In **2012**, projects use .Net 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0 or 4.5; you can change the version in Project Properties

Newer versions of Visual Studio support many versions of the .Net framework; check your project type and properties.

Comment: i m in 2008. but dont know which version is used by current project.

Comment: So go to Project Properties for the current project.

Comment: i got you. i can see version.

Comment: Then you should accept this answer by clicking the hollow check.

Comment: is it need to change web.config ?
<system.codedom>
<compilers>

Comment: @Niks: Yes (for ASP.Net projects)

Comment: I've updated the version to 3.5 in the project properties, but when I goto publish>prerequisites there is still .net 4.5 checked and hasn't changed. Does that mean the version hasn't been changed yet? @SLaks

Comment: What default version is the .NET Framework for VS 2008 express?

Comment: @RickardB.: The default framework for any VS version is the latest supported framework; you can see it in the New Project dialog.

Comment: @SLaks
So that would mean that in 2008, the .NET default framework would be 4.0?

Comment: @RickardB.: I mean the latest supported framework in that VS version.  2008 supports 3.5.

Comment: @SLaks
Thank you for the information, but did it support 3.5 as soon as it came out?

Comment: @RickardB.: .Net 3.5 was released together with VS2008.

Comment: Can this answer be updated for newer versions of VS?  This answer is the top google result for this question in general, not specific to VS version.

Comment: @levininja: For newer versions, it depends entirely on the project.

Answer (score 99):

#### VB Proj

Project Properties -> Compiler Tab -> Advanced Compile Options button

#### C# Proj

Project Properties -> Application Tab

Comment: Similarly in VS2019 - Properties -> Application -> Target Framework

Answer (score 54):

The simplest way to find the framework version of the current .NET project is:

1. Right-click on the project and go to "Properties."
2. In the first tab, "Application," you can see the target framework this project is using.

Answer (score 17):

You can also search the Visual Studio project files for the XML tag RequiredTargetFramework. This tag seems to exist on .NET 3.5 and higher.

For example: `<RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>`

You might have the element `<TargetFrameworkVersion>`, and learn more about the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3460066/1175496)

Comment: Worked well in a large solution to just use Notepad++ and search in file for all *.csproj files. One note though the value on my end had a **v** in front. <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>

Comment: There is a difference between `TargetFrameworkVersion` and `RequiredTargetFramework`

Comment: @Marcel what is the difference?

Comment: I guess, one is required, other is just set

Answer (score 6):

Simple Right Click and go to Properties Option of any project on your Existing application and see the Application option on Left menu and then click on Application option see target Framework to see current Framework version .

Answer (score 4):

**With Respect to .NET Framework 4.6 and Visual Studio 2017 you can take the below steps:**

1. On the option bar at the top of visual studio, select the 4th option "Project" and under that click on the last option which says [*ProjectName*]Properties.Click on it & you shall see a new tab has been opened.Under that select the Application option on the left and you will see the .NET Framework version by the name *"Target Framework"*.
2. Under Solution Explorer's tab select your project and press **Alt + Enter**.
3. OR simply Right-click on your project and click on the last option which says **Properties**.

Answer (score 2):

It's as easy as in your Visual studio.

1. go to the 4th menu option on top, 'website'.
2. under websites go to option, 'start options'.
3. under start options, go to 'build' option.
4. change the target framework there to what so ever framework.

Comment: There is no "website" in my menu of Visual Studio. 4th option is "Project". And the question wasn't about changing the framework...

Answer (score 2):

1. In **Solution Explorer**, open the context menu for the project that you want to change, and then choose **Properties**.
2. In the left column of the Properties window, choose the **Application tab**.
3. In the **Target Framework** list, you will see the current version of **.NET** framework on the project.
   You may also change the framework from there.

Comment: There is no Application tab on the left column of the properties window.

Comment: @ColePerry You have to right-click on one of the project, not on the solution. You should be seeing Application tab

Answer (score 1):

Open packages.config file all detail about packages and their versions which are installed into the current project listed there.
[follow given shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYAe4.png)

[here all installed packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhcpe.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the targeted version of either Windows or the .NET Framework if you create your project in Visual Studio 2013.
That option is not available anymore.

Look that link from Microsoft:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding you, this is absolutely not true.  The note you're referencing only applies to Windows Store apps.  Changing the targeted version of the .Net Framework is possible (and commonly done!) for the lion's share of project types.

Answer (score -1):

Updating for 2022...

refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?tabs=net60

| .NET SDK version | Visual Studio version |
| --- | --- |
| 6.0 | Visual Studio 2022 version 17.0 or higher. |
| 5.0 | Visual Studio 2019 version 16.8 or higher. |
| 3.1 | Visual Studio 2019 version 16.4 or higher. |
| 3.0 | Visual Studio 2019 version 16.3 or higher. |
| 2.2 | Visual Studio 2017 version 15.9 or higher. |
| 2.1 | Visual Studio 2017 version 15.7 or higher. |