# running a VS2005 code on Windows 2012 server

Tags: c#, iis, visual-studio-2005, windows-server-2012-r2

We have a C# code developed using VS2005 in a local machine. That code was hosted in a Windows 2003 server with IIS 6. Now that we are upgrading the server to Windows 2012 R2 (IIS 8.5 with IIS 6 Compatibility mode enabled), how do we make the code work on the new server.
I don't know much about VS/C#. The code is placed in C:\Intepub\wwwroot folder.
I tried to create an application in IIS Manager. But nothing works.
I get the below error:

> HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found
>   The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

I hope I am missing some simple logic. Kindly help me get through this.

Note: All we have is the code and VS2005/ that local environment is no more available.

Comment: We will need a whole lot more information. What kind of files are in the project, .aspx, or others? Because you are using Visual Studio 2005 that means your [code is .NET 2.0.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231632/how-to-find-the-net-framework-version-of-a-visual-studio-project). .NET 2.0 isn't installed by default on Windows Server 2012 so you could [install .NET 3.5 to get that](https://msincic.wordpress.com/2012/10/01/enabling-the-asp-net-2-0-on-windows-2012/).

Comment: Hi @Nanhydrin, thanks for the response. We have .aspx file and this site will connect to our Project's database and fetch User name and password for any given user.

Comment: @Nanhydrin is dotnet 3.5 alone enough to make the code work? I am getting the HTTP error message mentioned above. Should we need to do any changes in the way how the application is created in IIS?
Also what all are the application prerequisite to run this code in the new server.
Sorry that I am totally new to DOTNET and have very less knowledge about it.
Thanks for the help in advance!!!

Comment: 3.5 alone is unlikely to be all you need, and after you've installed it you will probably need to use aspnet_regiis to make IIS 8 aware of it. Once you've got that stuff installed I think you should go back to the beginning and search for a tutorial on installing a .NET web forms application into IIS 8/Windows Server 2012 and follow those instructions through with a clean website. Maybe start by working through [this](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/scenario-build-an-aspnet-website-on-iis)

Comment: @Nanhydrin!! Thanks for the valuable info! I will check these and come back to you! :)

Comment: @Nanhydrin Also can you please recommend a link on how to migrate the old VS2005 code to a later version of VS say VS2015.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have any sources to recommend for that, but if you just open the project in a later version of visual studio it will try to upgrade. If you can get your hands on versions 2008, 2010, etc. you could do it in stages and it might be easier.

Comment: Hii @Nanhydrin! Thanks for the inputs provided! Now that I have installed the recommended .net framework, the website is available! :)

Now the issue is with Database connectivity. The code uses Oracle DB and I need help in connecting the Application Server to database. I have enabled an ODBC OLTP Connection from the hosting server to DB. But the application doesn't get connected to Database. What am i Missing here?
Please help!!!

Comment: I would recommend that you add an answer to this question detailing what you did to solve the .NET/IIS problem so it's useful for other users. Then start a new question detailing the problem you're having with the database connection. I'm afraid I know precisely nothing about connecting to Oracle so creating a new question with the appropriate tags will bring it to the attention of people who do know :)

Answer (score 0):

As @Nanhydrin suggested, adding .net framework 3 to Windows 2012 server helped me fix the issue. in 2012 server, it can be done by using Add Roles and Features in server manager.