# Is there any way to find framework version of the project by means DTE or VSproject object?

Tags: c#, .net, vs-extensibility

I have an add in which is used to add dll to the project based on the framework of the project.for this i need to know the .NET Frame work of the project and i can achieve this by reading the .csproj file of the project. But what I am looking is Ways to get it via dte/vsproject object. is there any way?

Thanks,

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231632/how-to-find-the-net-framework-version-of-a-visual-studio-project

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/envdte.project(v=vs.110).aspx - Look at the remarks, might help. I believe you can get the version from the properties.

Comment: Thanks, I an access frame work from project property.

Answer (score 3):

You can get it from EnvDTE, using:

Project.Properties.Item("TargetFramework").Value

See:

[HOWTO: Get the target .NET Framework of a Visual Studio 2008 project from a Visual Studio add-in or macro](http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/articles/add-ins/)